# How to automatically change a particular word while writing to a file in python?

Tags: python, file

Say a method returns me a long list of lines which I am writing to file. Now on fly is there any way I can change the word "Bread" to "Breakfast", assuming word "Bread" actually exists in several places of my file that is being generated.

Thanks.

I have assigned the sys.stdout to file object, that way all my console print goes to file. So on fly hack would be great.

Comment: Do you want the list or the file to be changed?

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions.

```
import re

word = 'Bread'
rword = 'Breakfast'
line = 'This is a piece of Bread'
line = re.sub(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), rword, line)
# 'This is a piece of Breakfast'
```

The advantage of using regular expressions is that it can detect word boundaries (ie. the `\b`).  This prevents it from replacing words that contain your word (ie. Breadth).

You could do this line by line, or replace the word in the whole document at once.

Comment: Very good answer, but to do *all* the lines, you would need something like `lines = [re.sub(r'\b{0}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), rword, line) for line in lines]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is the *list* that you want to be changed rather than the file, and assuming that the list is called `lines`:

```
lines = [line.replace("Bread", "Breakfast") for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` string method, like:

```
text.replace('Bread', 'Breakfast')
```

Note that this doesn't check if it is a 'word', so it would also change 'Bready' to 'Breakfasty'.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace('bread', 'breakfast)` where bread is being replaced by breakfast.